# In Python3, when I'm reading a binary file why does 'b' become prepended to my content?

Tags: python

For example I'm trying to read a file as follows

```
fd = open('mydb.dbf', 'rb')
print(fd.read(1))
```

The output is:

> b'\x03'

I wish for only '\x03'. Where is the extra character coming from?

Comment: This is a fundamental conceptual change in Py3K. You should really go through the release notes carefully, especially everything to do with the `bytes` type: http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no extra character. You have a `bytes` object, whose contents are the single byte `\x03`.

The `print` function prints the `str` representation of any object. A `bytes` object prints out as `b'\x03'`. But that `b` is no more part of the value than the quotes are (or, for that matter, the backslash, x, or two digits).

To convince yourself of this fact, try `print(len(my_bytes))` or `print(my_bytes[0])`. The length is `1`; the first value is the (byte) number `3`.

(If you didn't want a `bytes` object, you shouldn't have opened the file in binary mode. But, considering that the first character is a control-C, you probably *did* want a `bytes` object.)

Comment: Why the rollback? That information was useful for the OP, no?

Comment: @HansEngel: No, it wasn't. The first character in the file is `\x03`; you really think that's UTF-8? And, if it is, the right thing to do is open it in text mode, not open it in binary mode and then decode piece by piece.

Comment: Still, the attempted edit was useful, because it inspired the extra line at the bottom, which I think might be helpful to the OP or others.