# charactrers from an rs232 sensor have a 'b' in front in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, byte, literals

I am reading characters from an ultrasonic sensor that outputs in RS232 format - it sends an R followed by 4 digits followed by a carriage return eg 'R1597\r'.

In python3 this is preceded by a 'b' so that it becomes b'R1597\r'. I have searched other related questions on stack overflow and as I understand it, this just indicates the characters are byte literals and the 'b' is not in the actual data. However the code;

```
char=ser.read()
while char != 'R':
    .......
```

does not work - it just loops forever waiting for 'R' to arrive.

But if I use the code;

```
char=ser.read()
while char != b'R':
.....
```

works - loops until b'R' arrives then goes on to the next piece of code.

So now I am confused, has python3 put a 'b' in from of the data that I now have to strip off?

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python3, when I'm reading a binary file why does 'b' become prepended to my content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845074/in-python3-when-im-reading-a-binary-file-why-does-b-become-prepended-to-my-c)

Answer (score 0):

No, the `b` is not injected into your data. The `b` tells Python 3 that the literal `'R'` should be interpreted as a byte rather than a string literal. A string character may be more than just a byte depending upon the underlying encoding (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.). In you're RS-232 case, you are receiving 7-bit ASCII characters (i.e. bytes), thus the `b` ensures that you are comparing bytes to bytes. For more information on byte literals, see [Section 2.4.1](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) of the Python 3 manual.